# NSMutableDictionary Retrieve Contents

Tags: nsmutabledictionary

I have a NSMUtableDictionary which holds an key with two objects in it, and another key with one object in it. How I retrieve the contents from both the keys. Any help is appreciated.

This is what i have in log. personalvehicleDict:{
    43 =     (
        "TempObject1",
        "TempObject2"
    );
    56 =     (
        "TempObject3"
    );
}

I want to retrieve data from both objects separately for key 43 and retrieve data for key 56 separately.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Am I right in guessing that the objects in the dictionary are NSArray (or NSMutableArray)?

If yes, then something like this should do the trick:

```
NSArray *arrayOne = [personalvehicleDict objectForKey:@"43"];
NSArray *arrayTwo = [personalvehicleDict objectForKey:@"56"];
```

Comment: Thank u so much for the reply.Yes that is correct. They are NSMutableArray objects.But for example i have mentioned the values hard coded as 43 and 56. But i have it as a string value- attribute personalvehiclepolicyattr. In that case how will this work. NSArray *arrayOne = [personalvehicleDict objectForKey:personalvehiclepolicyattr];
NSArray *arrayTwo = [personalvehicleDict objectForKey:personalvehiclepolicyattr]; Also my doubt is will both the values under key 43 will be retrieved.

Comment: This is how i set the NSMutableDictionary. [personalvehiclepolicydict setObject: self.driverarray forKey:personalvehiclepolicyattr];

Comment: Yes, you can use the variable you used to set the value to retrieve it as well. Both the values under key 43 will be retrieved - you can get the from the array by calling [arrayOne objectAtIndex:0] and [arrayOne objectAtIndex:1] respectively.

Comment: But my attribute string is personalvehiclepolicyattr. so how will I differentiate. can u please be more clear. Thanks

Comment: drivernewarray = [personalvehiclepolicydict objectForKey:personalvehiclepolicyattr];
   
        NSArray *new = [drivernewarray objectAtIndex:0];
        NSArray *newone = [drivernewarray objectAtIndex:1];   I tried with this code but i got this exception. *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
Any suggetions. Thanks

Comment: What type is personalvehiclepolicyattr anyways? To me it looks like you're overwriting the first object with the second when you're building the dictionary.